# How do we put various multivariable data in cluster bucket

Tags: clustering, multilevel-analysis

A data with multivariable of mixed types (Nominal and Continuous) are clustered using R package of Daisy/Agenes. How are we going to put the variables in the cluster bucket

I was thinking to put max count of levels in case of Nominal and quantile % in case of continuous.

Are these right way or my novice idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mixed data, the **cluster** package will compute dissimilarities using Gower's similarity coefficient (expressed as a distance). The [help file has details](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/cluster/html/daisy.html), on the implementation, but essentially

- **nominal** variables are treated as indicators: add 1 to similarity if samples $i$ and $j$ agree on the class for the $k$th nominal variable, or add 0 otherwise. This is reversed in **cluster** as it is producing a distance not a similarity.
- **continuous** variables and handled by taking the absolute difference of the values for the $k$th variable between samples $i$ and $j$. This difference is then divided by the range of the $k$th variable

  $$S_{ijk} = \frac{\left | x_{ik} - x_{jk} \right |}{R}$$

  where $R$ is the range and $S_{ijk}$ is the similarity between $i$ and $j$ on variable $k$. The dissimilarity/distance is simply $D_{ijk} = 1 - S_{ijk}$. The use of $R$ implies that the $k$ continuous variable is standardised and hence different units over the $k \in {1, 2, \ldots, K}$ variables are handled directly.

The similarity (or dissimilarity/distance) is then summed over the $K$ variables to give the similarity/distance between $i$ and $j$, for all pairs. Once you have this similarity/distance, hierarchical clustering in `agnes()` is performed in the same way as if the data were all continuous variables, because hierarchical clustering uses the distances between samples and not the raw data/observations.

Comment: Your reply is OK for clustering concept. The question is "How do we put various multivariable data in cluster bucket". In simple word which are constituents of cluster 1 and which are constituents of Cluster2 and so on.

Comment: Once you have the distance between each site the clustering proceeds as any standard hierarchical cluster analysis, that's what agnes() does. The type of data/variables is irrelevant once you have the distances. Is your question more about what is hierarchical clustering? If so, that's not clear from your question.